# Issue mapping a function to a TensorFlow dataset?

Tags: python, tensorflow

I have loaded a tensorflow record as a dataset. I'm trying to map the below preprocessing function to the dataset:

```
def preprocess_tensor(tensor, max_len=200):
  column_means = tf.reduce_mean(tensor, axis=0)
  nan_mask_filtered = tf.math.is_nan(tensor)
  x = tf.where(nan_mask_filtered, tf.expand_dims(column_means, axis=0), tensor)
  print(x.shape)
  if x.shape[0] < max_len:
      pad_size = tf.maximum(0, max_len - tf.shape(x)[0])
      pad_width = [(0, pad_size), (0, 0)]
      x = tf.pad(x, pad_width)
  elif x.shape[0] > max_len:
      x = x[:max_len, ...]

  return x
```

When I test this on 10 samples from the dataset, it works as intended, returning a tensor of shape (200,84)

```
sample = decoded_dataset.take(10)

# Iterate over the sample (since it's a dataset of size 1)
for data in sample:
    # Access the data fields of the sample
    coordinates = data['coordinates']
    phrase = data['phrase']
    print(coordinates.shape)
    new = preprocess_tensor(coordinates)
    print(new.shape)
```

Each sample shape is now (200, 84). But when I try to map this function to the whole dataset, I get the error:

```
decoded_dataset = decoded_dataset.map(lambda x: {'coordinates': preprocess_tensor(x['coordinates']), 'phrase': x['phrase']})

    File "<ipython-input-66-bed84c1fb88e>", line 2, in None  *
        lambda x: {'coordinates': preprocess_tensor(x['coordinates']), 'phrase': x['phrase']}
    File "<ipython-input-90-d39e15213a0f>", line 16, in preprocess_tensor  *
        if x.shape[0] < max_len:

    TypeError: '<' not supported between instances of 'NoneType' and 'int'
```

I'm also printing the shape which is showing (None, None). I don't understand why this function works when I'm iterating over the dataset, but not when I try to map it to the whole dataset?

Answer (score 0):

That's because all `tf.data` map operations run in graph mode, unless specified. See docs for [tf.data.experimental.enable_debug_mode](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/data/experimental/enable_debug_mode).

While in graph mode you'll most likely have None as the batch dimension, you need to catch it dynamically. Simply change `x.shape[0]` it to `tf.shape(x)[0]`.

Here's an example:

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np

def preprocess_data(x):
    batch_size_dynamic = tf.shape(x)[0]
    batch_size_py = x.shape[0]

    processed_x = tf.square(x)

    tf.print("batch_size_dynamic:", batch_size_dynamic)
    tf.print("batch_size_py:", batch_size_py)

    return processed_x

data = np.array([[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6]])
dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices(data).batch(2)

dataset = dataset.map(preprocess_data)

for batch in dataset:
    print(batch)
```

Prints:

```
batch_size_dynamic: 2
batch_size_py: None
tf.Tensor(
[[ 1  4  9]
 [16 25 36]], shape=(2, 3), dtype=int64)
```